# Unable to generate documentation for function definition followed by some macro #defines

Tags: c++, documentation, doxygen

I have a .cpp file and found that Doxygen is unable to document a function which contains the following format:

```
//!
//! \brief Test
//!        and perform operations on those points.
//!
void CTest::TestTri()
EH_Start("CTest::TestTri")
{
}
EH_Stop
```

The `EH_Start` and `EH_Stop` are an exception handling mechanism, and causing issues.

How can we exclude those?

Answer (score 4):

Try using a more explicit doxygen format - the following tells doxygen exactly which function you wish to document, so it doesn't have to understand your code to work out what to attach the documentation to:

```
/// \fn void CTest::TestTri()
/// \brief Test and perform operations on those points
EH_STart("CTest::TestTri") {} EH_Stop
```

Comment: I don't think the fn directive will work if Doxygen doesn't successfully parse that function at some point in the code base. It, like the 'class' directive, is intended to let you relocate documentation. It is not intended to let you add arbitrary function doc for non-existent functions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming EH_Start and EH_Stop are defines, you can have doxygen expand those macros when it processes the code

```
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED = EH_Start EH_Stop
```

We have a number of macros for function and class declarations.  Without `EXPAND_AS_DEFINED`, doxygen will not generate the correct documentation

For example:

```
/* C++ Code */
#define STANDARD_CONSTRUCTORS_HEADER(iCLASS) \
  public:  iCLASS(); \
  public:  virtual ~iCLASS(); \
  private: iCLASS(const iCLASS & iCopy); \
  private: iCLASS& operator=(const iCLASS &);

class Foo {
  STANDARD_CONSTRUCTORS_HEADER(Foo)
}

/* Doxyfile */
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED = STANDARD_CONSTRUCTORS_HEADER
```

Without `EXPAND_AS_DEFINED`, you won't get the Foo constructors in the documentation.