# Add section with custom items to class documentation?

Tags: c++, doxygen

The Doxygen documentation for a (C++) class has various sections like "Public Member Functions" and "Private Attributes". I would like to add a custom section with entries that are not members of my class. Is there a way to do it?

Specifically, my classes have* methods like `SetProperty(std::string name, int value)` that takes various property names and I would like to document the valid options for property names. Right now I'm listing the private fields that back the properties, and putting the property names in the comments, which is a bit suboptimal.

---

*) Before someone suggests to just change the code, this interface is there for reasons out of my control and I can't change it. The idea is to allow loose coupling and to set properties of classes in scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Doxygen supports the notion of [Member groups](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html#memgroup), which is precisely what you're looking for. Simply enclose the members like this:

```
struct MyClass
{
  int nongroup_member;

  /*!
    \name MyGroupName
    Group description
    Note that this entire block is optional
  */
  //! @{
  int member_in_group;
  int another_member_in_group;
  //! @}
};
```

If the members you want to document in the group don't actually exist as members, you should be able to introduce "fake" declarations for them inside and `#ifdef ... #endif` block controlled by a macro which will only be defined for the Doxygen run.

Comment: Thanks, the member groups work (but I have to add \nosubgrouping to the class so the group appears on the same level as the others). However, the fake members don't work for me. It seems doxygen still expects the member to be declared in code somewhere else.

Comment: @jdm The fake members should work, at least on their own. Can you try them without the group, to make sure you have the syntax etc. correct?

Comment: I double-checked it, and I get `Warning: documented function \`int CP::MyClass::fakeMember' was not declared or defined`, and it doesn't show up in the documentation. See also [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/973903#comment5547577_977958)

Comment: @jdm Hm, I thought it was supposed to work :-( I've offered an alternative solution.